# How to forward HTTP response

Tags: java, http, request, response, http-status-codes

I've got flow like this one Client -> API A -> API B -> API A -> Client

This is endpoint in API B. When exception is thrown I want to pass error message in HTTP response to my Client.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> get (@RequestParam(name = "userId") String userId) {
        try {
            User user = userService.findUserById(userId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (SampleException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

When I am doing it the way above this is what my Client gets.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-24T08:30:19.637+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "400 null",
    "path": "/getUser"
}
```

But when I change my code to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> get (@RequestParam(name = "userId") String userId) {
        try {
            User user = userService.findUserById(userId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (SampleException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

response:

```
<200,No such user has been found,[Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"27", Date:"Fri, 24 May 2019 08:33:51 GMT"]>
```

It works perfectly fine but I dont want to have any errors as 200 OK. Is there any reasonable way to fix it?

Comment: where the code in api A handle error when call to api B?

Comment: Well what do you want to have instead of the error message in the 200 response?

Comment: the response is fine, i just want to have it as an error, not 200. but it seems I cannot return in API B anything except 200 cause the real message won't be passed down to client

Comment: Maybe you want to return a `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` ?

Comment: case is I cannot return any of 4XX cause when I do it, my message error is not in response which goes back to client.

Comment: When I send my HTTP request right to endpoint in API B, it works fine with BAD_REQUEST, the Clients gets my error message. The case is when i send request through API A I cannot use BAD_REQUEST cause response stops at API A I think.

Comment: Can you fix API A?

Comment: So does the problem lie in API A? To be honest I dont have any clue where to begin with

Comment: Well, you could make API A hand through unknown codes like HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND from API B to the caller of API A.

Comment: Was is the exception in API B that leads to the "Internal Server Error"? Could you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: I divine that the exception is a "No such user has been found" - SampleException which is thrown by findUserById. I think it should be handled as a HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND status

Comment: ```org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 null      
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
 at com.PEP.service.EntityService.getMainAppResult(EntityService.java:87) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.PEP.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:31) ~[classes/:na]```

Comment: @Adder, I know that NOT_FOUND 'd more appropriate but as I mentioned earlier, all 4XY responses are invalid, I always get                                                           ```{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-24T08:30:19.637+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "400 null",
    "path": "/getUser"
}```

Comment: This comes from API A, right? So you need to fix API A if you have the sources and time. An API should not give status 500 Internal Server Error unless there is a bug in the code.

Comment: Yes, this comes from API A.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue has been solved. In my API A I was using RestTemplate. I needed to create my ResponseErrorHandler and then use `restTemplate.setErrorHandler()` method. Thanks guys for your help.